# Not able to train the model in server (Graph execution error:)

Tags: python, tensorflow, server, tf.keras, multi-gpu

I am trying to train a V-Net model for CBCT dataset using Keras (tensorflow) library. But my local server is not able to train it. It is showing error. Please, somebody, help me in solving this issue.

Note: I am using 8 number of GPUs for training.

But the same code is working in Google Colab. The code is given in link below.

```
https://github.com/bkpphysics/V-Net/blob/main/unet3d_model.ipynb
```

Here is the error

```
2023-06-13 16:44:25.871685: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:428] Loaded cuDNN version 8801
2023-06-13 16:44:25.897413: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:428] Loaded cuDNN version 8801
2023-06-13 16:44:25.911459: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_ops_3d.cc:1563 : UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
2023-06-13 16:44:25.922997: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:428] Loaded cuDNN version 8801
2023-06-13 16:44:25.923082: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_ops_3d.cc:1563 : UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
2023-06-13 16:44:25.926710: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_ops_3d.cc:1563 : UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
2023-06-13 16:44:25.947966: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:428] Loaded cuDNN version 8801
2023-06-13 16:44:25.948061: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_ops_3d.cc:1563 : UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
2023-06-13 16:44:25.972134: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:428] Loaded cuDNN version 8801
2023-06-13 16:44:25.972203: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_ops_3d.cc:1563 : UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 7
      5 # model.summary()
      6     model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 7     history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 1, epochs=100,validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
Detected at node 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 561, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 511, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1132, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/conv3d_transpose.py", line 314, in call
      outputs = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(
Node: 'replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose'
9 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_285]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_277]]
  (2) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp_15/_234]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_269]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_273]]
     [[group_deps/_447]]
  (3) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp_15/_234]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_269]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_273]]
     [[group_deps/_443]]
  (4) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp_15/_234]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_269]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_273]]
  (5) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp_15/_234]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/_269]]
  (6) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp_15/_234]]
  (7) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3528): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
     [[{{node replica_6/model/conv3d_transpose/conv3d_transpose}}]]
  (8) CANCELLED:  Function was cancelled before it was started
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_62820]
```

Comment: show the last line of the of the full traceback, along with full traceback written. Don't post images. It's highly not recommended here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to cpu it's work on me because sometime GPU is Not able provide efficient Memory to model